# SVD Matlab Implementation

Tags: matlab, svd

I tried to write matlab code that would decompose a matrix to its SVD form.

"Theory":

To get U, I found the eigenvectors of AA', and to get V, I found the eigenvectors of A'A. Finally, Sigma is a matrix of the same dimension as A, with the root of the eigenvalues on the diagonal in an ordered sequence.

However, it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
A=[2 4 1 3; 0 0 2 1];

% Get U, V
[aatVecs, aatVals] = eig(A*A');
[~, aatPermutation] = sort(sum(aatVals), 'descend');
U = aatVecs(:, aatPermutation);

[ataVecs, ataVals] = eig(A'*A);
[~, ataPermutation] = sort(sum(ataVals), 'descend');
V = ataVecs(:, ataPermutation);

% Get Sigma
singularValues = sum(aatVals(:, aatPermutation)).^0.5;
sigma=zeros(size(A));
for i=1:nnz(singularValues)
    sigma(i, i) = singularValues(i);
end

A
U*sigma*V'
```

U * sigma * V' seem to be returned with a factor of -1:

```
ans =

-2.0000   -4.0000   -1.0000   -3.0000
0.0000    0.0000   -2.0000   -1.0000
```

What's the mistake in the code or "theory" that led to it?

Comment: I wrote about this last May: [Calculating SVD by hand](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1805239/339790).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The eigenvectors are not unique (because `Av==λv` by definition, any `w` with `μw==v` and `μ~=0` is also an eigenvector). It so happens that the eigenvectors returned by `eig` don't match up in the right way for SVD (even though they are normalized).

However, we can construct `U` once we have `V`, which we will find as eigenvectors of `A'*A` as in your algorithm. Once you have found `V` as sorted eigenvectors, you have to find `U` to match. Since `V` is orthogonal, `A*V == U*sigma`. So we can set

```
U = [A*V(:,1)./singularValues(1) A*V(:,2)./singularValues(2)];
```

and indeed, `A == U*sigma*V'`, and in particular the `U` found here is exactly the negative of `U` found with your algorithm.

Comment: While eigenvectors are not unique, the normalized eigenvectors should be, no?

Comment: @AnaM No, because `norm(v) == norm(-v)`, and with `n` eigenvectors you have `2^n` combinations of orthonormal vectors.

Comment: Wouldn't some convention to have first element as positive fix this issue?